# Decision stump in Python

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to transfer Matlab code to Python, and get exactly the same result. In Matlab code, I have a decision stump as follows:

```matlab
switch Model
    case 'DecisionStump'

        Weights = Pt; % Train the weak learner by weights Pt

        tree = fitctree(X,Y,'minparent',size(X,1)-sum(Weights==0),'prune','off','mergeleaves','off','Weights', Weights, 'CategoricalPredictors', CategoricalPredictors);

        h = compact(tree);
```

and I used python code below to construct exactly the same decision stump:

```
clf_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 1)
```

However, I get slightly different results by these two programs, and It would be great if any one can help me if I miss anything. (perhaps categorical predictors should be included in my python code, but I do not know how!)

Comment: The Python code doesn't use any data. I don't see how that code could ever be equivalent. Please post sufficient code for people to copy-paste and run. This is called a [mcve]. Include some data in that too. But do note the "minimal" concept!